# How to calculate evaluation matrix(accuracy, precision, recall, f1 score) for multiOutput Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, cross-validation

I want to evaluate SVM which predicts more than one column. So I use multiOutput. Here is my code:

```
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
linear_svc=MultiOutputClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', C=C))
```

I use cross validation:

```
scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
           'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score)
          }



results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator=linear_svc,
                                          X=X_train_,
                                          y=y_train_,
                                          cv=kfold,
                                          scoring=scoring)
```

But i can't. please help